# How to continue after the breeding room?

Tags: metroid-other-m

Adam has ordered me to investigate Sector 1, and after leaving the Breeding Room (after the cutscene) the door locks after me.

The main route has been blocked by a blast shield BEHIND a door, for which I need Super Missiles, but Adam hasn't authorized them yet. How do I continue? There is nothing in the hallway, and in the control room nearby, there was an enemy in a pod which I shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recall exactly, but it was one of the following ways to get out, from most to least likely.

1. A morph ball tube you can grab near the blast shield.  You may need to blow open a hatch over it first using missiles first.
2. A secret passage in the control room under the pod the creature was in.
3. A secret passage near the bottom of the staircase in the Blast Shield room.
4. Wall jump in the Blast Shield room.
5. A secret passage in the hallway... although I think that was the hallway on your way into the Breeding Room.

The reason I list this many is these techniques are used in various places in the game, and I don't recall which one this area used.

Comment: it was 2. you need to be morphball to actually enter the area to enter the entrance for the tube... that was confusing.